# Some warnings after installing gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Greet everyone, after gradle installation via brew I have that warnings:

```
➜ gradle -v
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.9/libexec/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-07-16 08:14:03 UTC
Revision:     efcf8c1cf533b03c70f394f270f46a174c738efc

Kotlin DSL:   0.18.4
Kotlin:       1.2.41
Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          10.0.2 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.2+13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
```

I use it without any problems but still.. How to fix them?

```
➜ java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Gradle when using Java 9/10.

There are some workarounds available for it, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2995 for more details.